# I might need some help on this Complex Fourier Series Problem

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Here is the problem:

Use the complex Fourier Series on $[-L,L] $ with complex coefficients to find a representation of

$\frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} |f(x)|^{2} dx$

Here is my attempt:

The complex Fourier Series is represented as

$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n e^{\frac{n \pi x}{L}}$

Initializing the absolute value function would imply

$|f(x)|^{2} = |\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n e^{\frac{n \pi x}{L}}|^{2}$ 
            $ \leq |\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n|^{2}*|e^{\frac{n \pi x}{L}}|^{2}$ = $|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n|^{2}$

This is by Cauchy-Schwarz. Am I on the right track about this?

I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: You need some assumptions on $f$ to ensure that $f(x)$ is **equal** to its Fourier series pointwise, if that is your goal. Also, you have improperly applied C-S, first because you didn't use norms, and second because $(\exp{n\pi x\over L})_n\not\in\ell^2(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: You need to use $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{-m \pi x}{L}} \mathrm{d} x = \delta_{n,m}
\end{align*}

I.e. the basis functions $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}}$ are orthogonal.

So note that for $N$ finite, we have

\begin{align*}
& \left \| \sum_{n = 0}^N C_n \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}} \right \| \\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^N \vert C_n \vert^2
\end{align*}
 With the inner product defined above, we have

\begin{align*}
& \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^L \left \vert \sum_{n = 0} ^\infty C_n \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}} \right \vert^2 \mathrm{d} x \\
& =  \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^L \left \vert \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{n = 0} ^N C_n \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}} \right \vert^2 \mathrm{d} x \\
& =\left \| \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{n = 0} ^N C_n \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}} \right \| \\
& = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left \|  \sum_{n = 0} ^N C_n \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}} \right \| \\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \vert C_n \vert^2
\end{align*}

You may move the limit in front of the norm because norms are continuous.

Comment: Okay I see what is happening. Now my next question is this: If f(x) is a real function, how would I rewrite the integral presented in the first question in terms of the usual Fourier Coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ ?

Comment: You can also represent a real function with complex exponents. You have to allow for negative indices though, i.e. $n$ runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I am having trouble typing out my work on here to be honest. I expressed the cosine and sine parts of the Fourier Series in terms of the exponents. I do not understand why I have to use those indices.

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}} = \cos{(\frac{n \pi x}{L})} + \mathrm{i} \sin{(\frac{n \pi x}{L})}$. So, suppose you perform the real Fourier transform and you find the coefficient $A_n$ in front of $\cos{(\frac{n \pi x}{L})}$. If you perform the complex transform correctly, it will find you $c_n = \frac{A_n}{2}$ and $c_{-n} = \frac{A_n}{2}$, too. Then you have $c_n \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{n \pi x}{L}} + c_{-n} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{-n \pi x}{L}} = A \cos{(\frac{n \pi x}{L})}$ (the same).

Comment: I should mention that this is only true if the prefactor of the sine with the same frequency $B_n = 0$.